# iOS Background image doesn't work on device

Tags: ios, image, background, device

This is my prob :

I add this to my code :

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgWhiteLight"]]];
```

And it's works fine in the iOS simulator, but when i test it on real device, it doesn't work at all. Note that I redefine the

```
self.navigationItem.titleView
```

But there no pb at all in the simulator, only on real device !

Thanks

Comment: Can you try with real name like `bgWhiteLight.png` instead of just `bgWhiteLight` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes Specifying just the name of file is not enough, You can do something like this

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bgWhiteLight" ofType:@"jpg"];
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgWhiteLight.png"]]];
```

Try this. Give the full name of the image

Answer (score 0):

On the device the names are case sensetive. 
make sure it's exactly the name.